# Getting the URL from current iexplore tab in batch

Tags: url, batch-file

I would like to use a batch file to obtain the URL in the current Internet Explorer tab.  I know that this is possible in languages such as C#.  I would like to learn if it is possible using a batch file.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@for /f "tokens=10 delims=," %A in ('tasklist /fo csv /v /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe"') do @Echo %A
```

Best you can do in batch is get window title which might have the url.